# Determine if a grid contains another grid

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, grid, subsequence

## Challenge

Create a function takes in two 2-dimensional arrays of characters (or strings if the programming language does not have characters as a datatype) as inputs: a and b. If your language does not support these inputs, you may use any other standard one-byte variable.

Your task is to determine if b contains a. If this is so, return true. Otherwise, return false.

## Sample Test Cases

```
a:

123
456
789

b:

123
456
789
```

should return true.

```
a:

code
golf

b:

thisis
code!!
golf!!
ohyeah
```

should return true.

```
a:

abcd
efgh
ijkl

b:

abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
```

should return false.

```
a:

abc
def

b:

1abc2
3def4
5ghi6
```

should return true

```
a:

ab
cd

b:

#ab##
##cd#
```

should return false

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so least bytes wins.

Comment: Hi and welcome to codegolf! I edited your test cases to (hopefully) make them a bit more clear. Note that we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) for working on challenges before posting them to main. Good luck!

Comment: Also, may I take the first array as an array of strings and the second as a string separated by newlines, even though my language(C#) has a character type built in?

Comment: @Neil Test cases 2 and 3 are not square.

Comment: Could you add a truthy test case where `a` isn't on `b`'s left edge and a falsey test case where each line of `a` appears in consecutive lines of `b` but with their left edges staggered?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance yes

Comment: Please add test cases: `['abc','def'], ['1abc2abc7','3abc4xxx8','5ghi6'] -> false` and `['abc','def'],['1abc2abc7','3abc4def8','5ghi6'] -> true`

Comment: What's the minimum grid size? If it's 1x1, I recommend test cases involving a 1xY and Yx1 grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 4 bytes

```
s\s\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzimOOb//@hopRIlHaUMIM4E4mI4HasTrZQMZOUDcQoQpwKxIhiDZNKhMjlAnIYikw81rRKqJxHMjwVZhGocpjGxsQA)

Most easily run as a full program, as usual for a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem), with *a* specified as a command-line argument, *b* on standard input. The question asks for a function, and the program also works as a function, with *b* on the left, *a* on the right, and output via [producing an exception if and only if the decision is  false](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/76359).

### Explanation

```
s\s\
s     a substring of rows of {the left input}
 \…\  assert rectangular; swap row and column operations
  s   a substring of <s>rows</s> columns of {the above matrix}
      {implicit} assert that the result can be {the right input}
```

The "assert rectangular" is, obviously, pointless, as the question guarantees that already. The rest of the program does the grid-finding for us by identifying a substring of the rows and of the columns, i.e. a submatrix.

### Meta-discussion

We've had a [very similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178188) before; I'd expect most answers to one question to be modifiable into answers to the other. I think this is the neater version of it, though.

Comment: Shortest answer here, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,r=4:b*r and f(a,b[1:],r)|f(a,zip(*b)[::-1],r-1)or a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBboQgEIbP@hQsJ9mwyarYbk14EuIBVlhoVVilh2367nbQNtmkF5j/m3/yZyY8ovVTta6GD3JUvUSSKjpz1qrjjOTUI1MAEWXb0Zl8J/HlQnFURLTtqQR4KokHJ@dqjXqJC@JIZELgq@81pvjmB4M7KnC0bnELkNQ4HH5bW@HtQ0uLu47mWRotqxooa17gfb28beP/2J9ZqmsPTJubhc@9fwzgRzvXJsXYDVI8Tj7c5@cYgDXb7TU7n2uIQIDLirFUAWFNAwOoy3MDW6ZTEOQmtG3a5pnkowxF/AyDppLkmXrSCnSY3RT3E5L1Bw)

Takes input as lists of tuples of characters.

Tries all sub-grids of `b` and checks if `a` is among them. The sub-grids are generated by recursively branching on either removing the first row of `b` or rotating it 90 degrees. After exactly four rotations, checks if the trimmed down `b` is equal to `a`.

Comment: @mazzy I think the input grids are supposed to be rectangles.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>21</s> <s>15</s> <s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

```
1#.,@E.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoIwFEX3fsVFDZWIT7HGAQMhMTo5uToVbC2KVsXF8PEIkhjjcN9wz33nVPeIa0QhOHxMETYZE1a77aYO@uQna6o99sxkqSLCPoTKjEVFzThwq@bGSRViCe3Gk2Q4cyvyGJMRBaOcBET3Cdks2gQfNsMcA/DMHtTRFpqzNKI5Fm33NHmZly1xnJY5jjUvJQ3/EaVfkehEMs0OSh9NfjoXH5noZL/95Wpv98e/ZspY/QY)

*-7 bytes thanks to Bolce Bussiere*

### original answer

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 15 bytes

```
<@[e.&,$@[<;.3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy7DoJAFET7/YrBGFYjXoU1FgiGxMTKypZYLLCw@FoVG8PHI0hijMXcYs6dc2wGxHOEPjgczOG3mRI2@922CaJYke0MozhYkTg0Y/ZMZaVCQuxDpdqgpnbk2nV711HtY4XcXs@ikWfXNGZMhuROShIQ/RKy/ejifpiHBYbgqclUYc45Z0lICyy77qnLqqw6YlkdsyyjX0pq/iNKviLRi2SSZiovdHk8nT8y0ct@@8vV3O6Pf82cseYN)

*-6 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

### how

- `<@[` boxed left arg
- `$@[<;.3]` all rectangles in the right arg with the same shape as the left arg
- now pass those as the left and right arg to...
- is the left arg an elm of the right arg, after flattening both `e.&,`

Comment: I think this can be `<@[e.&,$@[<;.3]`

Comment: Ah ofc, ty!  If you want a challenge, have a look at [this monstrosity I defiled the site with](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/hostile-divisor-numbers/185172#185172)

Comment: -7 Bytes: `+/@:,@E.`. E. is pretty much made for this challenge.

Comment: tyvm @BolceBussiere.  i will update this tonight.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
⌈⭆η⭆ι⁼θＥ✂ηκ⁺Ｌθκ¹✂νμ⁺Ｌ§θ⁰μ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYw9C8IwFEV3f8VrphQi6Ozk4CBYKHQMHUIam2A@TJNK/fUxsQXxwYV7D4fHJZu4YzqldlI24oYtyswGdzHPsWFPLAn8hiJw8TPTAXsCBXRacVGcB4FWzwHfhB2jxL7OKOeYszqWgPl3zvFqB7GUV4c6e@brr3dKiVLE3SAQ2QGg0ek76nOlKEoVVFhxVYxq68XZupNvwSTq@7R/6Q8) Link is to verbose version of code. Heavily based on my answer to [Count the contiguous submatrices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178173/), the only difference being that instead of taking the sum of the matches I take the maximum, and because of the implicit string conversion due to the use of `⭆` the result is already a string which saves a byte.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>46</s> 37 bytes

```
Partition[#2,Dimensions@#,1]~FreeQ~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY@9DoIwFIV3ngLbxOku@O9gwmCcdSYMFYtUBRS6mAZfHS/1gmhMHL60p73n9DQVOpGp0CoSdbyqt6LQSqs8C/gI1iqVWYmi9Dl44WNTSLl78GG9LVSmgzjgPAyHvu87xnGNMR6MYFyB47qumcAUZrSfwwKWlRV/hxqFUSxiwHLkgEhGM@xIpxckZm0k0ygTRCFlt7amzyhgA8vvyO/bnJLv5BVWv2s2eo9ENr91Sco6vqbptGl1Qs72ta78ZwSQuV@v/VrPTLcpqow@cEVuSNHUc6r6CQ)

Returns `True` if b does *not* contain a, and `False` if it does.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
øŒεøŒI.å}à
```

Takes `b` as first input, `a` as second. Both inputs as character-matrices.

Port of [*@Mr.Xcoder*'s 05AB1E answer for this related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178180/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I6jk85tBZGeeoeX1h5e8P9/dLRSiZKOUgYQZwJxMZyO1YlWSgay8oE4BYhTgVgRjEEy6VCZHCBOQ5HJh5pWCdWTCObHxnJFo5uHaU5sLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/spuSZV1BaUmyloGTv6WKvpJCYlwJmhuoo@ZeWAKVAMv8P7zg66dxWEBmhd2hR7eEF/3UObbP/Hx2tVKKko5QBxJlAXAynY3WilZKBrHwgTgHiVCBWBGOQTDpUJgeI01Bk8qGmVUL1JIL5sbFc0ejmYZoDUWUIZBsBsTFYhQmQZQrEZmCeOZBlAcSWZKgFuSQJiJPBLgCpSIW6Ph3iRqAIyO9ZQJwNdhM2fTpQXTDXw0IOSRdQJhfIyoP6rQCIC4G4CGgeAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
øŒ          # Get the sublists of every column of the (implicit) input `b`
  ε         # Map each list of sublists to:
   øŒ       #  Get the sublists of every column again
            #  (now we have all sub-matrices of `b`)
     I.å    #  Check if the second input `a` is in this list of sub-matrices
        }à  # After the map: check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

### [JavaScript (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), <s>131 112</s> 105 bytes

**105 bytes:**

```
f=(m,n)=>m.some((x,i)=>i<=m.length-n.length&x.some((c,j)=>n.every((l,z)=>(m[i+z]+'').indexOf(l,j)==2*j)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDvaoMwFMW/@xR@WpI1FWZbGHTuFfoAIiOzUePyp6iI7cu743R1HWLgQO753Zt7b0rRijqt1KXZtq99n0XUcMuidxPUzkhKO64QqbfIBFravCm2dro8dVNKykuk2EC2srpSqvkNITWx2tySDSEsUPYsu1MGgsQofC4ZY30rKl/oSyH8yI9jIggnn1AKnSFJEu75f09MMvg5VEAKKhdyvuBryEAWciRJjp43dGtk3Xy8/LYb7Lsbju48wAPdjXR5LPRcngVgHuD@1v7/ugtl844PpYextBi7DVulztZOy0C7nGb05zf5tCZjxxUcruPdOt6v4wNw/w0)

Changes:

- `m[i]` into `x` and `n[z]` into `l`: *Totally forgot that these variables were already instanciated*
- `&&` into `&`: *Both sides of the operator are already booleans so a bitwise operator will work*

---

**112 bytes:**

```
f=(m,n)=>m.some((x,i)=>i<=m.length-n.length&&m[i].some((c,j)=>n.every((l,z)=>(m[i+z]+'').indexOf(n[z],j)==2*j)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDvaoMwFMW/@xR@apI1Dcy2UOiyV9gDhDAyGzUuf4qKdL68u05X1yEKPzDnnJt7b0rVqjqtzLXZtae@zzh21BP@6lgdnMb4Rg2czAt3zGqfN8XOTz@bjRNGTrGUlhDzTLe6@sLY0g6OGALbTm4RIsz4i769ZdiLTg5ZnjyVhJC@VVWs7LVQMY@FQApR9AGkwAXQSNIo/vsJlIGeAwVggHIh8wm6BRzggYCkPEfR0K3RdfP@/NtukO9qMqrzAA/ufnSXx4Key7OAMQ9wv@vwf92FsnnHh9LjWFqM3Yat0uDrYDWzIccZ/nlNOq1JyHnFTtbt/bp9WLePYPff)

Changes:

- `map((c,j)=>{...}).some(s=>s)` into `some((c,j)=>{...})`: *Redundancy*
- `m[i+z].join()` into `m[i+z]+''`: *A shorter way to convert the array into a string*
- `indexOf(n[z].join(),j)` into `indexOf(n[z],j)`: *The* `indexOf` *method already converts* `n[z]` *into a string*

---

**131 bytes:**

```
f=(m,n)=>m.some((x,i)=>i<=m.length-n.length&&m[i].map((c,j)=>n.every((l,z)=>m[i+z].join().indexOf(n[z].join(),j)==2*j)).some(s=>s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDvaoMwFMW/@xR@apItDcy2UOjSV9gDBBmZjRqXP2JEur68u85O1yEGfpCck5tzbyrZyZA1um633bHvc44tdYSfLQveKoyvVMNJv3LLjHJFW27dfbPZWKFTZmWNcUYruOWY6lTzhbGht@EJoZ9vKau8dpgw7S7q@pZjJyZtKOLJU0XIGBb4ORDSd7KJpalLGfNYCCQRRR9ABlwAhVIaxX@XQDnoBVACGqgW7nyCbgALOMCjND1F0ZDWqtC@v/zGDfKkJqM6N/Dg7kZ3uS3IXO4FjLmB6a39/3EXyuYZH0oPY2k5pg1TZd4FbxQzvsA5/vlNeh@TkNOKnazbu3V7v24fwO6/AQ)

Readable:

```
function f (m, n) {
  return m.some((x, i) => {
    return i <= m.length - n.length
      && m[i].map((c, j) => {
        return n.every((l, z) => {
          return m[i + z].join().indexOf(n[z].join(), j) == 2 * j
        })
      })
        .some(s => s)
  })
}
```

Instead of compairing individual values, I checked if the lines from grid N were included in the lines of grid M, and if so, at which indexes. If all of the lines are included starting from the same index then the grid N is contained in the grid M.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
1∊⍷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/BRR9ej3u3/0x61TXjU2/eob6qn/6Ou5kPrjR@1TQTygoOcgWSIh2fwfw1jBeNHvVsMFYwUjBVMFEwVzBTMFSwULDUV0hRwyykoPOqdq1BSVJrKpWGkYAJUpJ6cn5Kanp@Tpg7WaaJgBhIsycgsziwGSSkqgiQVFfMzKlMTM4CKEAYYQwxITEpOSU1Lz8jMys5Rh1pvhi6Rm5dfUFikDnNBWmJOMdgJxgiFML2mICFDoJiRMVDUxBRogBlYIxwg@8EIZgBEuxFEu3JikjIQJKcoo@pEMgDsBAA)

It's like this question was made for APL!

### Explanation

```apl
  ⍷   ⍝ 'find', returns a matrix with '1' in all positions where the first matrix is contained in the second
1∊    ⍝ checks if '1' is a member of this matrix
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>106</s> <s>118</s> 113 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,L=len:any(sum(A==B[j:j+L(A)]for A,B in zip(a,b[i:]))==L(a)for i in range(L(b))for j in range(L(b[0])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNboQgFIXX@hQMK0hZOIr9MWHhrH0D6gJnQLEKVu3Cvry9OG3Sphu4@c45Obl32tbOu3Q34nUf1NjcFFKsYZUYtCuU28jyMZJSiIvsi/6hIiWtjZ9RyS7IOvRpJwJ2aYuaUiEqomhQbdBm5VpNKtLQg/V/mEwgQPdVL@uCBJKRlPjqbxoz3PrB4JpJvHZ2sQuQIJxO39Ix@G7TqsN1zeIoRM9pBpTnj/A@Pb8c8X/sx6ya6w2YNm0Hn@3fBvCjO9cm1HQHZHh0fnqff9cAzPjdnvEkyaACAT6nnIcJCM9zCKA6jsPW4To0bH5sWsTRNFu3InPw/Qs)

Comment: @Neil: Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>71</s> <s>102</s> <s>85</s> 98 bytes

thanks @Jo King; test cases added.

```powershell
param($a,$b)!!($a|%{$p=[regex]::Escape($_)
$b|sls $p -a -ca|% m*}|group index|?{"$a"-ceq$_.Group})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZVtb4IwEMff8ymqdAMWNPPZmZi5F8ve7Qssi6lwCBsKUs1YxM/urmh1U4yMQNLQ3v3vftwl9MLgCyLugu9vqUOGZL0NWcRmOmUmnRiVCm6SmzUNh28RTCF@HwyeucVC0OnYUOgk4T4nNCQ1RmoWKsnsbpNMo2AVEm9uQ5w8rquUVWsWLOi4/iIcG2O7UZSRriimrhB8NItxIA3NJHQZrcBMjaO9r9FsaTuL1u505bbXf9DSnWHmUBqKcQJrZsOswAYZOA1854yxdD3ucSkR8krld8DxFLjfwNwMdEugHebzEzabWLYMBmfqyr338emffYcQg3Mgu6lof5rNg3ARZZDb2UVjLhkqcp61Ff1NKWihoi0PHeR2szj1@@IkXL0/NFz968RGcWIcx0WIzWJEpBWtsVViV/EzchDbJRGRlrPGTiHiLp95FZ9F7F7@H/9XJB5ytrVXUlsFMU9bOxdLPNxk9hlOZRNVlX5VtWw1I/PF5tVLvlN6F0BPJVxeBknIDVmndipor2wGiIM4BGsJtiDjMMOXN8cJScc7ZQR85S/RcIuDM1UIQeqrUn3vTgefTGQMZJR5BFWVzfYH)

Less golfed:

```powershell
param($a,$b)

$matches = $a|%{
    $pattern = [regex]::Escape($_)
    $b|Select-String $pattern -AllMatches -CaseSensitive|% Matches
}

$relevantGroupsByMatchPosition = $matches|group index|?{
    "$a"-ceq$_.Group  # the '$_.Group' contains matches in source order
                      # -ceq is case sensitivity equation operator
                      # -ceq performs an implicit conversion to the left operand type
}

!!($relevantGroupsByMatchPosition)  # true if the variable is not $null
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, 150 bytes

```js
f=(a,b)=>{_='length';for(r=i=0;i<=b[_]-a[_];i++)for(j=0;j<=b[0][_]-a[0][_];j++){u=0;a.map((l,y)=>l.map((c,x)=>u=u||b[i+y][j+x]!=c));r=r||!u;}return r}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dZDRasMgFIbv8xTmSkNs6eXAnUH7GiLFuCQ12FhMDA1Nnz3TOUJhmxefHr/Df8ROTnJQTt/G3fS2rg0QSasCPh5nwKbu2/GCWWMdcaDhwPQ7VPwsdjKA6bIsouqC6KI4iOS@d9YF/fDByf1V3ggxdA65JhWK3kPhwS9LxXU5C96Vd5GDKgrmwC1L7tnT1aN3PXLPdZIOHREgnqGwOFaYImwjPiNqLOiPaTdjIhosMsGyLAacXgLGKC8ROmJ4OW1Rv4YE5An/j/ujx26z5i1Hprv0OGX7wZp6b2xLGnKk6BR@Yf0C)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 81 bytes

```javascript
(m,n)=>m[s='some']((a,i)=>a[s]((b,j)=>!n[s]((c,k)=>c[s]((d,l)=>m[i+k][j+l]!=d))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBtC4IwFIW/@yvs0yatoDcIYv2RMWJOzZfpwol/345aWSEOHrg7x7tzr7lqldN19mg27blLeEdLVgX8WgrHibNlTCSlimWQlHCoQ5ajXlXDRbMCFz3UETNDX7YupMjXRq54FOB0rap9ZR6p8rkvBFGEkRBoEAEkMM//PoIk0O8gBRnIZ74poBtQggpYIuXF8/q0JnbNbfeO6@WPuh/VaYAf9zC682Mhc34WGNMAn7eO/@vOtE07/rSextZ0TOu30rZy1sRbY@80ocPfZK81g@CyYO@X7cOyfVy2T7C7Jw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/[Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), <s>47</s> <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 40/38 bytes

- -2 Default output to `ans`
- -1 Trace of inner product is the sum of the squares of the elements. Therefore use `trace(a*a')` instead of `sum(a(:).^2)`
- -4 Use `find` instead of `any(any(...))` since any non-zero output of `find` is considered as a logical truth, and Matlab/Octave is 1-indexed.
- -2 but only in Matlab, since the second argument to `xcorr2` does not need to be made numeric and is implicitly converted to whatever is the first argument's type.

### Octave

```matlab
@(a,b)find(xcorr2(a*1,b*1)==trace(a*a'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNNb9swDL3nVzCHwFKrFP7ALkkNtMA2YPYGFEtvaQ6yLSNqUsmQlM3Yn88o2UnabjVgmZb4HslHSteO/xLH4x3hrKKtVA3pa21MSvhVwqqrhOa5M7wW@M8jSo@mgxzuiKVQb7khhqtGknWWQZKmG2YpXcIMfnBnZA@6BX@uX6AzUjle7UVA8doJYycFMmVLKPGTxB62kn@E9SgOCIPqBg1pIeszBpW3krhP4kmrDUgPWqQxonAZozhhnZ0APm0I2JIoz3N4/LJ6hFkDaD@piEkaXMLCkcZ0pMCsq8EsxwJ24sQ6JhP8B9QMHjw9uK2AF19qLd6FHQXgQGZx2vR@oQuIWMGKIbqv4TlPFgU7Y2YWHTh5ZgtKmVDNW8YnNXJWyImMA1/JygvfDvnKd3wV2X3EF73WQSpff8v3VizDjhx6dxvffMJ6P4taNgJ@bwXWbMBp6A7Od0ehOUqDj5@NYSLKecHWCUs3dHk@rcg6XqSb644klJ3MlFIE8YvXmIozB3HZPKcdBkIqPw4KOm2lk1p5RRgq4rvbjQEFVvIBXGkXKLwEo/Oozqm9Pw8qNLc9qNoHCNtG2MPe@WSVDbflLFSv8SKEU@azp//GnU6n8PX@23dA41XY/@Y4n8/h4X61AjTepojv8fgX)

### Matlab

```matlab
@(a,b)find(xcorr2(a*1,b)==trace(a*a'))
```

This works by computing the [2D cross-correlation function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) of matrices `a` and `b` (in a numeric from), and then checking whether an entry corresponding to a perfect overlap exists.